# symfony2 FOSElasticaBundle : how to postpone document updating when elasticsearch service is down?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I am using symfony2 and FOSElasticaBundle.

My elasticsearch service often gets killed or fails for a still unknown reason. I've put systemctl in place with `restart always` as a temporary fix.

Still, if down, the elasticsearch listener which performs an update of the index when doctrine updates an entity gets me an error 52 :

> Couldn't connect to host, Elasticsearch down?

So this happens at logging if also using FOSUserBundle which updates the last user connexion date. That's super annoying to have such a depedency on elasticsearch. I've put an exception listener on this error but I'd prefer to have the bundle keep the update for a later time when the service is available again.

Looking into the bundle files, I found :

> vendor/friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle/Persister/ObjectPersister.php

```
public function replaceMany(array $objects)
{
    $documents = array();
    foreach ($objects as $object) {
        $document = $this->transformToElasticaDocument($object);
        $document->setDocAsUpsert(true);
        $documents[] = $document;
    }

    try {
        $this->type->updateDocuments($documents);
    } catch (BulkException $e) {
        $this->log($e);
    }
}
```

This is a service and I hopped in could be overwritten as follows but it is a class that another one inheritates and child ones are instantiated instead of called as a service so I don't see how to overwrite it. How could I ?

```
    try {
        $this->type->updateDocuments($documents);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        if ($e instanceof BulkException)
        {
            $this->log($e);
        }
        elseif ($e->getMessage() != "Couldn't connect to host, Elasticsearch down?")
        {
            throw $e;
        }
    }
```

Then, how can I make sure the document is updated next time the service is available ?

EDIT:

My trace when I get the error:

```
Stack Trace
in vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Transport/Http.php at line 153   -
        }
        if ($errorNumber > 0) {
            throw new HttpException($errorNumber, $request, $response);
        }
        return $response;
at Http ->exec (object(Request), array('connection' => array('config' => array('headers' => array()), 'host' => 'localhost', 'port' => '9200', 'logger' => 'fos_elastica.logger', 'enabled' => true))) 
in vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Request.php at line 167   + 
at Request ->send () 
in vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Client.php at line 587   + 
at Client ->request ('_bulk', 'PUT', '{"update":{"_index":"foodmeup","_type":"user","_id":4}} {"doc":{"firstName":"Dominique","lastName":"Descamps","content":null,"username":"ddescamps","email":"ddescamps@ebp-paris.com","jobSeeker":{"skills":[],"experiences":[],"trainings":[]}},"doc_as_upsert":true} ', array()) 
in vendor/friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle/Elastica/Client.php at line 47   + 
at Client ->request ('_bulk', 'PUT', '{"update":{"_index":"foodmeup","_type":"user","_id":4}} {"doc":{"firstName":"Dominique","lastName":"Descamps","content":null,"username":"ddescamps","email":"ddescamps@ebp-paris.com","jobSeeker":{"skills":[],"experiences":[],"trainings":[]}},"doc_as_upsert":true} ', array()) 
in vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Bulk.php at line 342   + 
at Bulk ->send () 
in vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Client.php at line 270   + 
at Client ->updateDocuments (array(object(Document))) 
in vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Index.php at line 131   + 
at Index ->updateDocuments (array(object(Document))) 
in vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Type.php at line 174   + 
at Type ->updateDocuments (array(object(Document))) 
in vendor/friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle/Persister/ObjectPersister.php at line 144   + 
at ObjectPersister ->replaceMany (array(object(User))) 
in vendor/friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle/Doctrine/Listener.php at line 151   + 
at Listener ->persistScheduled () 
in vendor/friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle/Doctrine/Listener.php at line 182   + 
at Listener ->postFlush (object(PostFlushEventArgs)) 
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/ContainerAwareEventManager.php at line 63   + 
at ContainerAwareEventManager ->dispatchEvent ('postFlush', object(PostFlushEventArgs)) 
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php at line 3318   + 
at UnitOfWork ->dispatchPostFlushEvent () 
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php at line 428   + 
at UnitOfWork ->commit (null) 
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php at line 357   + 
at EntityManager ->flush (null) 
in src/AppBundle/Model/Classes/CustomBaseController.php at line 61   + 
at CustomBaseController ->flush () 
in src/AppBundle/Controller/Core/VoteController.php at line 68   + 
at VoteController ->voteAction (object(Request), 'up', 'Post', 'permettre-le-partage-de-documents-avec-les-equipes') 
at call_user_func_array (array(object(VoteController), 'voteAction'), array(object(Request), 'up', 'Post', 'permettre-le-partage-de-documents-avec-les-equipes')) 
in app/bootstrap.php.cache at line 3029   + 
at HttpKernel ->handleRaw (object(Request), '1') 
in app/bootstrap.php.cache at line 2991   + 
at HttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true) 
in app/bootstrap.php.cache at line 3140   + 
at ContainerAwareHttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true) 
in app/bootstrap.php.cache at line 2384   + 
at Kernel ->handle (object(Request)) 
in web/app_dev.php at line 36   +
```

Comment: Are you on app_dev? I've had issues with symfonys custom error handler before, I couldn't catch exceptions for some reason I don't remember.
If not: are you sure the exception is of type BulkException?

Comment: arf, that's it, I did not see the try catch was only filtering bulk exceptions.

Comment: By the way if you use the ES for logging, then use logstash. Logging should be as fast as possible, thus async is the preferred way. You can use monolog.

Answer (score 1):

Message queue perfectly fits your requirements. You send a message to MQ whenever your model is updated. That's it for web process. Then you have a pool of workers that consume messages from the MQ and are trying to update ES index. If the ES is down right now there will be an exception, the worker dies and the message returned to the queue. So the message is still in MQ, once the ES is online workers do their job.

The Same pattern could be used not only with ES but any other 3rd party service. For example, you want to send a very important email but mail server is down, you cannot wait now you have to send a response to the customer. So put it to the MQ and let a broker and workers do their job.

Here's a code of how it could be done using [enqueue](https://github.com/php-enqueue/enqueue-dev) MQ library. Installation and configuration are [pretty easy to do](https://github.com/php-enqueue/enqueue-dev/blob/master/docs/bundle/quick_tour.md) so I'll skip it.

The standard listener has to be replaced with one that sends messages:

```
<?php
use Enqueue\Client\ProducerInterface;

class ElasticaUpdateIndexListener
{
    private $producer;

    public function __construct(ProducerInterface $producer)
    {
        $this->producer = $producer;
    }

    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $entity = $eventArgs->getObject();

        $this->producer->sendCommand('elastica_index_entity', [
            'entity' => $entity->getId(),
            'type' => 'insert'
        ]);
    }

    public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $entity = $eventArgs->getObject();

        $this->producer->sendCommand('elastica_index_entity', [
            'entity' => $entity->getId(),
            'type' => 'update'
        ]);
    }

    public function preRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $entity = $eventArgs->getObject();

        $this->producer->sendCommand('elastica_index_entity', [
            'entity' => $entity->getId(),
            'type' => 'delete'
        ]);
    }
}
```

The processor for this messages looks like this:

```
<?php

class ElasticaUpdateIndexProcessor implements PsrProcessor, CommandSubscriberInterface
{
    private $doctrine;

    protected $objectPersister;

    protected $propertyAccessor;

    private $indexable;

    public function __construct(Registry $doctrine, ObjectPersisterInterface $objectPersister, IndexableInterface $indexable)
    {
        $this->indexable = $indexable;
        $this->objectPersister = $objectPersister;
        $this->propertyAccessor = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }

    public function process(PsrMessage $message, PsrContext $context)
    {
        $data = JSON::encode($message->getBody());

        if ($data['type'] == 'delete') {
            $this->objectPersister->deleteManyByIdentifiers([$data['entityId']]);

            return self::ACK;
        } 

        if (false == $entity = $this->doctrine->getManagerForClass($data['entityClass'])->find($data['entityId'])) {
            return self::REJECT;
        }

        if (false == ($this->objectPersister->handlesObject($entity) && $this->isObjectIndexable($entity))) {
            return self::ACK;
        }

        if ($data['type'] == 'insert') {
            $this->objectPersister->insertMany([$this->scheduledForInsertion]);

            return self::ACK;
        }

        if ($data['type'] == 'update') {
            $this->objectPersister->replaceMany([$this->scheduledForInsertion]);

            return self::ACK;
        }

        return self::REJECT;
    }

    private function isObjectIndexable($object)
    {
        return $this->indexable->isObjectIndexable(
            $this->config['indexName'],
            $this->config['typeName'],
            $object
        );
    }

    public static function getSubscribedCommand()
    {
        return 'elastica_index_entity';
    }
}
```

And run some workers:

```
./bin/console enqueue:consume --setup-broker -vvv
```